# How to concatenate a list of dicts with inner lists

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts with inner lists and dicts, I need to concatenate them in one big dict.
The list is like this:

```
[{'total': {'last_day': '7'}}, 
 {'total': {'progress': '07/04'}}, 
 {'total': {'piecies': '3008'}}, 
 {'total': {'week': ['16.0']}}, 
 {'total': {'week': ['17.0']}}, 
 {'total': {'week': ['15.0']}}, 
 {'total': {'week': ['17.0']}}, 
 {'total': {'week': ['16.0']}}, 
 {'total': {'week': ['13.0']}}, 
 {'total': {'week': ['6.0']}}, 
 {'tkts': [{'tktvalue': '13.5'}]}, 
 {'tkts': [{'month': {'consuntivato_pezzi': '2346'}}]}, 
 {'tkts': [{'month': {'consuntivato_euro': '31671.00'}}]}, 
 {'tkts': [{'month': {'preventivato_pezzi': '9897'}}]}
]
```

I have tried some for loops and recursive functions, without great results

```
for vars in temporary_var:
    for title in vars:
        try:
            try:
                table_var[title].update(vars[title])
            except KeyError:
                table_var[title] = vars[title]
        except AttributeError:
            table_var[title].append(vars[title][0])
```

But I can obtain only this:

```
{'total': {'last_day': '7', 'progress': '07/04', 'volumes': '3008', 'week': ['6.0']}, 'tkts': [{'service': 'SOSPC'}, {'tktvalue': '13.5'}, {'month': {'volumes1': '2346'}}, {'month': {'volumes2': '31671.00'}}, {'month': {'volumes3': '98
97'}}]}
```

but i need this:

```
{'total': {'last_day': '7', 'progress': '07/04', 'volumes': '3008', 'week': ['16.0', '17.0', '15.0', '17.0', '16.0', '13.0','6.0']}, 'tkts': [{'service': 'SOSPC', 'tktvalue': '13.5', 'month': {'volumes1': '2346', 'volumes2': '31671.00', 'volumes3': '9897'}}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it gets the output that you want:

```
lst=[{'total': {'last_day': '7'}},
 {'total': {'progress': '07/04'}},
 {'total': {'piecies': '3008'}},
 {'total': {'week': ['16.0']}},
 {'total': {'week': ['17.0']}},
 {'total': {'week': ['15.0']}},
 {'total': {'week': ['17.0']}},
 {'total': {'week': ['16.0']}},
 {'total': {'week': ['13.0']}},
 {'total': {'week': ['6.0']}},
 {'tkts': [{'tktvalue': '13.5'}]},
 {'tkts': [{'month': {'consuntivato_pezzi': '2346'}}]},
 {'tkts': [{'month': {'consuntivato_euro': '31671.00'}}]},
 {'tkts': [{'month': {'preventivato_pezzi': '9897'}}]}
]

d={} # the dictionary that will hold the result

for dd in lst: # for each dictionary in the list of dictionaries
    for key,value in dd.items():
        if key not in d: # key does not exist in dictionary d
            d[key]=value

        else: # key exists in dictionary d
            if isinstance(value,dict): # check if the value is a dictionary or a list
                for key1,value2 in value.items():
                    if key1 not in d[key]:
                        d[key]={**d[key],**value} # combine the dictionaries
                    else:
                        d[key][key1].append(value2[0])

            elif isinstance(value,list): # check if the value is a  list
                if isinstance(value[0],dict): # check if the value is a dictionary or a list
                    for key1,value2 in value[0].items():
                        if key1 not in d[key][0]:
                            d[key][0]={**d[key][0],**value[0]}
                        else:
                            d[key][0][key1]={**d[key][0][key1],**value2}

print(d)
```

Output:
{'total': {'last_day': '7', 'progress': '07/04', 'piecies': '3008', 'week': ['16.0', '17.0', '15.0', '17.0', '16.0', '13.0', '6.0']}, 'tkts': [{'tktvalue': '13.5', 'month': {'consuntivato_pezzi': '2346', 'consuntivato_euro': '31671.00', 'preventivato_pezzi': '9897'}}]}

Comment: Thanks, but I copied your code and obtain AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append' in the line: d[key][key1].append(value2[0])

Comment: In yout opinion, how can I do the same thing with a recursive function?

Answer (score 0):

Try using default list here. You can learn more about them [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)
for sequence in (yourdict):
    for keys,dictionary in sequence.items():
          result[keys].append(dictionary)


print(dict(result))
```

Output :

```
{'total': [{'last_day': '7'}, {'progress': '07/04'}, {'piecies': '3008'}, {'week': ['16.0']}, {'week': ['17.0']}, {'week': ['15.0']}, {'week': ['17.0']}, {'week': ['16.0']}, {'week': ['13.0']}, {'week': ['6.0']}], 'tkts': [[{'tktvalue': '13.5'}], [{'month': {'consuntivato_pezzi': '2346'}}], [{'month': {'consuntivato_euro': '31671.00'}}], [{'month': {'preventivato_pezzi': '9897'}}]]}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the output that I look for, the week dictionary must contain a single list with all the data, like this {'week': ['16.0', '17.0', '15.0', '17.0', '16.0', '13.0', '6.0']}

Comment: Okay , I will try and combine the week lists